# Exporting OpenTelemetry to Dynatrace in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, open-telemetry, dynatrace, exporter

I'm designing an infrastructure for application tracing with the following constructs:

1. The applications are written in .NET 6
2. The logging protocol is OTLP
3. The logging target is Dynatrace
4. Looking at multi-organizational microservices with potential heavy tracing

Keeping in mind the expected heavy concurrent workload, what would make better sense to use?

- the Dynatrace dedicated exporter or
- a logging framework (e.g. Serilog with a Dynatrace sink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynatrace does not offer a custom exporter for OpenTelemetry Logs.
Maybe you got confused by the [Dynatrace metrics exporter](https://github.com/dynatrace-oss/opentelemetry-metric-dotnet)? Dynatrace also does not offer a Serilog sink.

Dynatrace offers HTTP proto OTLP ingest for the stable signals - [Traces](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/extend-dynatrace/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-traces/opentelemetry-trace-ingest-api) and [Metrics](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/extend-dynatrace/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-metrics/opentelemetry-metrics-ingest-api).

The Logs API/SDK is [not yet stable](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/issues/2911). I'd expect Dynatrace to follow suit and offer  the same ingest channel for OTel logs once it gets into a mature state.

Currently, you can still ingest logs following one of the approaches listed here: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/extend-dynatrace/extend-logs

Comment: Thanks.

It means Dynatrace relies fully on its OneAgent so it does not use exporters, except for the metrics data.
As for the Serilog Sink to Dynatrace – there is such a sink but Serilog's format is less verbose than OpenTelemetry's and therefore missing critical elements in the solution. Plus it focuses on logs only.
The remaining question is – when coming to implement heavy tracing in my applications using OpenTelemetry and exporting it, let's say to Zipkin: is the Zipkin Exporter reliable enough to handle the load or should I use some logging framework to do it?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear. For sending OpenTelemetry traces and metrics from your .NET apps,
you can use the official [.NET OTLP exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol)
to send traces and metrics directly to the Dynatrace OTLP ingest API. You don't need a OneAgent for this.

Comment: For OpenTelemetry Logs, Dynatrace doesn't offer an API endpoint to ingest OTLP logs **yet**. As stated, when OpenTelemetry Logs are marked as stable. I'd expect Dynatrace to offer the same ingest channel as for traces and logs when OTel logs are mature enough - meaning you can use the same .NET OTLP exporter for all three signals. No need for any custom framework/exporter.
About the serilog sink you mentioned - that sink is provided by the community, not by Dynatrace.

Comment: As for your question about heavy tracing and Zipkin. Zipkin is a tracing solution, not logs. Not sure what you meant by "using another logging framework to do it". For "Is Zipkin reliable" is also probably something you need to try with your use-cases, or ask the Zipkin community. You can always scale the instances and all that, so it really depends I'd guess.
For the question of heavy tracing and using OpenTelemetry, your question (if related to performance) is probably better directed to the .NET SDK repo or Slack channel.

Comment: I ask it because I read a few months ago that the exporters are not built for high loads, but I can't seem to find that web page. It does make sense when looking at the OTLP exporter sources, it's http send request is fully synchronous and might result in trace loss, timeouts and performance impact. Anyway, thanks a lot for all the information.